# GROUP BY id showing newest entry of same ID

Tags: mysql

I know this has already been asked answered a thousend times. But I seem not to be able to resolve this.

I am trying to group by and order this query so I can join it as subquery to a bigger query

```
SELECT * FROM `ggorderlog` 
WHERE `GGTITLE` LIKE '%Reklamation%' 
ORDER BY `GGDATE` DESC, `ggorderlog`.`GGORDERID` DESC
```

This is the result from the ggorderlog table and the query above

```
GGTITLE     GGOXID    GGDATE             GGORDERID GGTITLE               User
Reklamation uniqueid1 2018.12.7 16:20:00 1         Reklamation created   Max Mustermann
Reklamation uniqueid2 2018.12.7 16:24:00 1         Reklamation finished  Maxine Musterfrau
Reklamation uniqueid3 2018.12.7 16:22:00 2         Reklamation created   Max mustermann
```

Now what I want is to have this table be displayed so that for every GGORDERID I only see the latest entry. In order to give an overview over the User who has worked on this and the status of the ticket.

Like this:

```
GGTITLE     GGOXID    GGDATE             GGORDERID GGTITLE               User
Reklamation uniqueid2 2018.12.7 16:24:00 1         Reklamation finished  Maxine Musterfrau
Reklamation uniqueid3 2018.12.7 16:22:00 2         Reklamation created   Max mustermann
```

I tried standard group by with order by but mysql seem to do the group by first and give out a random column

I tried this but it still shows always a random date.

```
Select* from (
      Select *
      from ggorderlog as b 
      where GGTITLE like '%Reklamation%' 
      ORDER BY b.GGDATE DESC
) b2
  group by b2.GGORDERID
```

I tried a lot of other suggestions with left itselfe or group_concat and then desolve again but nothing seems to work.

Comment: is ggdate a datetime field ?

Comment: yes, it is a datetime field

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
SELECT gg.*
FROM ggorderlog gg
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ggorderid, MAX(ggdate) AS maxggdate,oxid
    FROM ggorderlog
    GROUP BY ggorderid) groupedgg 
ON gg.oxid = groupedgg.oxid
AND gg.ggdate = groupedgg.maxggdate
```

Comment: So this one kinda gives me back those entries that have only one entry in the ggorderlog, opposed to only the latest